# Autopromote users when they link an OpenID to their account?

Tags: php, openid, mediawiki

I'm using MediaWiki with the [OpenID](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OpenID) extension, and would like the wiki to autopromote users that link their OpenID(s) to their editing accounts, and autorevoke them if there are no linked OpenIDs. I know the MediaWiki syntax for autopromotion, but do not know the event ID triggered when an OpenID is linked/unlinked.

Comment: This issue is now filed and can be tracked in the MediaWiki Extension:OpenID bugtracker as https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44165 . Please fell free to contribute there.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this feature, the OpenID extension needs to have hooks.

**What are hooks?**

Hooks in MediaWiki are events subscription facilities: they are arrays of functions to call when a specific event occurs.

For example, the UserSetEmail hook will allow any functions to be called when an user sets a email.
[More information about hooks](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks).

**We need OpenID extension hooks.**

As soon *UserSetOpenID* and *UserUnsetOpenID* hooks will be available, you will be able to add your autopromotion code in a function, called by these hooks:

```
$wgHooks['UserSetOpenID'][] = 'PromoteUserOnOpenID';

function PromoteUserOnOpenID ( $user, &$OpenID ) {
    //The promotion code
}
```

Please [fill a feature request](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=MediaWiki%20extensions&component=OpenID&cc=dereckson%40espace-win.org&bug_file_loc=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fq%2F14343703%2F1930997&bug_severity=enhancement) on our bug tracker (I prefilled a little the bug form). I will follow your feature request to make sure this is readily available.

Thank your for this question, this is a valuable feedback to improve the OpenID extension.